# Suggestions for the study material on JavaFX

Tags: javafx

As I am switching from Java to JavaFX, what is some good study material regarding JavaFX which has complete data?

Comment: You can browse the README of this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mhrimaz/AwesomeJavaFX). It lists many things related to JavaFX including books and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java FX cookbook by Adreas Pomarolli will be good. Link: [JavaFX PDF](http://index-of.es/Varios-2/JavaFX-Programming-Cookbook.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In market we have Java editions available in the name of Black Book, by dream tech that will be useful for beginners they will provide examples.

We can get it in Flipkart [Link to Filpkart](https://www.flipkart.com/java-8-programming-black-book/p/itme7fu2kr95cgpb).

Comment: What is *"dream tech"*? A company?